# Prove that: $ \sum_{1}^{n}{ \cos^2{x_i}} \le n\cos^2{\frac{\pi}{2n}}$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

I am looking for a proof of the problem following:

Let $0 < x_i < \pi/2$ for $i=1, 2, 3,..., n$ and $\sum_{1}^{n}{ x_i=\pi/2}$ .

Prove that:  $ \sum_{1}^{n}{ \cos^2{x_i}} \le n\cos^2{\frac{\pi}{2n}}$

Comment: Have you tried by induction?

Comment: Lagrangian multiplier may come in handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we can use [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality). $\cos^{2}$ is concave on $0 < x < \frac{\pi}{2}$ and therefore 
  $$ \cos^{2} \left( \frac{1}{n} \sum x_{i} \right) \geq \frac{1}{n} \sum \cos^{2}(x_{i})$$

Comment: Actually, I think this is wrong because $\cos^{2}$ is only concave on $0 < x < \frac{\pi}{4}$, it was my mistake I was picturing $\cos(x)$ in my head. I believe my proof will work for $\cos(x)$ but not $\cos^{2}$. Any comments?

Comment: Also note that the question has been changed since the posting of both the current answers and so neither currently make sense

Comment: I've also since updated my answer (the community wiki) accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

First let's note that the restriction $0 < x_k < \pi/2$ combined with $\sum_{k=1}^n x_k = \pi/2$ means that we must have $n \ge 2$.

Equality is clearly obtained when $x_1 = x_2 = \cdots = x_n = \frac{\pi}{2n}$.  I think, and maybe I'm wrong, that it can be shown using multivariable calculus that this equality is actually the maximum.  At the very least we can show it's **a** maximum.  I don't know if multivariable calc is above your level or not and I generally don't like to provide answers above the OP's level, but I'm not sure how else to get started (maybe induction?) and it's an interesting problem.

Here's an outline of how to get started using multivariable calculus:

1. Define $f(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n) = \sum_{k=1}^n \cos^2(x_k)$.
2. Note that $f_{x_k} = -\sin(2x_k)$ for all $k$.
3. Therefore $f_{x_{kk}} = - 2\cos(2x_k)$ for all $k$ and $f_{x_{kj}} = 0$ for all $j \ne k$.
4. This means the [Hessian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix) has a structure so simple that finding its eigenvalues is trivial.
5. If $n \ge 3$ and if $x_1 = x_2 = \cdots = x_n = \frac{\pi}{2n}$ then the Hessian matrix is positive definite.  This means that $f$ [has a local max](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test#Functions_of_many_variables) at $(x_1, \dots, x_n) = (\frac{\pi}{2n}, \dots, \frac{\pi}{2n})$.

It still remains to show that this is actually the *global* max.  The case $n = 2$ also need to be considered.  Note that $n=2$ won't work in step 5 above because then the Hessian matrix is the zero matrix and we can't draw any conclusions from that analysis.

Comment: that's why $0 < x_i < \pi/2$ out there. This is not a good counterexample.

Comment: Right, thanks, knew I missed something.  Will remove for now.

Comment: No, you don't missed. Because I tyrpo when the first post. Iam sorry. Good luck to you, and happy. @tilper

Comment: @OaiThanhĐào, my very first post claimed that it wasn't true and I gave a counterexample, but the counterexample was bad because it didn't satisfy all of the hypotheses.  That's what I was referring to.  I'll try to update the post with the fixed conditions.